# Add existing project to several solutions visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project, solution

I have one solution (a) that has several projects (1,2,3)

I want to take one of the projects (say 2) and make it part of another solution also (b)

so that solution (a) consists of projects {1,2,3}
and solution (b) consists of projects {2,4,5,6}

Is that possible in VS2012?

Comment: You should probably consider, at this point, whether the two solutions should be sharing that project, or whether it should be broken out into a 3rd solution, and the first two solutions should include the compiled outputs of that solution via non-project references. This may or may not be the case, but it's usually worth spending a bit of time thinking about it.

Comment: @user2612387 Would be nice if you can give some feedback to the leaved comments and answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Of course it is.** You add the project (2) in solution (b) via *Add -> Existing Project*.
But be careful changes in one solution on project affects your other solution as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are including a project to a solution that has not yet used Nuget and the project you are including does, you have to add the .nuget folder or you will get an error:

**.nuget nuget.targets was not found**

on the project.  The easiest way to add the folder is to:

1. Install Nuget.
2. Right click on the solution and select "Enable NuGet Package Restore".
3. Click Ok on the warning.
4. Close and re-open the solution.